# Weird problem in calculating sum of two computed field values as another sum

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have created one content type having fields like A,B,C,D,E,F,G. I have used computed filed module to compute these fields like the following. (Used filed group module to group some A&B in first group, C&D in second group , E,F,G are in third group.
Here are the computations

A*C=E

B*D=F

E+F=G WHERE E,F AND G are computed fields .

The problem is when I submit the content type first time I am able to get E and F values but not G and if I edit the node and submit the result of G(E+F) is displaying correctly.

Here is the code snippet used to computed fields

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_a['und'][0]['value'] * $entity->field_c['und'][0]['value'];

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_b['und'][0]['value'] * $entity->field_d['und'][0]['value'];

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_e['und'][0]['value']+ $entity->field_f['und'][0]['value'];
```

**Display Output**

```
$display_output= $entity_field_item['value'];
```

We tested the same scenario in Articles content type with field groups which shows all the results at a time i.e E,F and G.

I am getting errors on first submit.

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_e in eval()

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_f in eval()

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this suggestion works

Go to the computed filed settings of **G**. Uncheck "Store value in the database" option might solves your problem. (If not necessary to store)

Comment: Hey.. it worked for me.